# How many non-repetitive instances can a $1$ to $14$ cars park in $14$ park spaces.

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

Here are the $14$ park spaces. 1 car has 14 possible spaces now how many possibilities does $2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14$ cars have.

[image]

Comment: Are the cars considered unique?  Have you heard of the multiplication principle before?  Break into steps for three cars labeled car1,car2,car3.  Choose where car1 parks (how many choices?) Choose where car2 parks (how many choices?) Choose where car3 parks (how many choices?).  What does multiplication principle imply about the total number of possibilities then?

Comment: They are not unique.

Comment: So if we have two cars, a toyota and a ford, and they are parked in spaces $1$ and $2$, it doesn't matter if it was toyota then ford, or if it was ford then toyota?  All you care about is which of the spaces are occupied.  If we have $14$ total spaces and we want to **choose** four of them to be occupied how many ways can we do this?  Have you heard the phrase "14 *choose* 4" before?

Comment: I have not but i will look into it

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank very much please come again.

Answer (score 3):

If the cars are not considered unique, This essentially is a problem of using the binomial coefficient. Take $n \in [14].$ Since I have $14$ spaces to choose from for $n$ cars, I can do this $\binom{14}{n}$ ways. Thus, given $n \in [14]$ was arbitrary, the number of ways I can park $1$ to $14$ cars in $14$ spaces is $$\sum_{i=1}^{14} \binom{14}{i}.$$

Comment: I expect the intention of the problem was to have a specific $n$.  In your interpretation, you allow $n$ to change.  If that was the intended interpretation, note that your answer could be made much simpler since $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{14}\binom{14}{i} = 2^{14} = \binom{14}{0}+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{14}\binom{14}{i}$, so your answer would simplify to $2^{14}-1$

Answer (score 0):

The answer is just $13$ factorial.

Given that one space is taken, your 13 remaining cars can simply be placed in the remaining 13 spaces.  13 choices for for the first car, 12 for the next, 11 for the next and so on down to 1.  That gives $13!=6227020800$

Answer (score 0):

If you mean how many ways are there are arranging 13 filled spaces and 1 empty space, then the answer is simply 14 - as it's a simple question of which of the 14 spaces will be empty.